# How do I load JSON synchronously in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to build an HTML5 game, but I've run into a problem. I'm attempting to design the game so it can be modular; my method of doing this was to have a JSON file with the different modules to load.

The code I've tried

```
var resources = {};

$.ajaxSetup({
  async: false
});

$.getJSON('res/gen/generators.json', function (data) {
  resources.generators = data;
});

for (let generator in resources.generators) {
  $.getScript("res/gen/" + resources.generators[generator].folder + "/script.js");
}

$.ajaxSetup({
  async: true
});
```

The JSON file

```
{
  "memoryless": {
    "folder": "memoryless",
    "name": "Memoryless",
    "description": "Generates a piece with no regard to the previous history."
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting an error that says "[Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.", but I don't want the any other code to run until these load. What should I do?

Comment: put them in the callback

Comment: learn how to deal with what the first A in AJAX stands for ... Asynchronous ... by the way, what you are getting is not an error, it's a warning, so your code works as you want it to

Comment: The next thing to learn is to do this without jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Fighting against the asynchronous nature of JavaScript will lead to a "not nice" development experience. Embrace asynchronicity.

Here we start nesting promises and callbacks:

```
var resources = {};

$.getJSON('res/gen/generators.json', function (data) {
  resources.generators = data;

  $.when(Object.keys(resources.generators).map(function(generator) { 
    return $.getScript("res/gen/" + resources.generators[generator].folder + "/script.js");
  }).then(function() {
    ...do other stuff
  })
});
```

Alternatively you could use [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await):

```
(async () => {
  var resources = {}
  resources.generators = (await $.getJSON('res/gen/generators.json')).data;

  for (let generator in resources.generators) {
    await $.getScript("res/gen/" + resources.generators[generator].folder + "/script.js");
  }
  ...do other stuff
})()
```

And as another alternative, you could abandon your custom module system and use standard [JavaScript Modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules):

```
import memoryless from "res/gen/memoryless/script.js"
```